# How to put arrows between sections on the same row using twitter bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to put arrows between these four section boxes as shown in my picture below. Currently I have the below boxes ([codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVERvm?editors=1010))

I've added the following html between the boxes, but it does not produce the effect im going for since it moves all the arrows to one side

```
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
```

See below for my code:

```
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title></title>
  <style>
    .ibox {
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;

    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='container'>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class='ibox'>
          <h2>Safari bug warning!</h2>
          <p class="text-danger">As of v9.1.2, Safari exhibits a bug in which resizing your browser horizontally causes rendering errors in the justified nav that are cleared upon refreshing.</p>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class='ibox'>

          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class='ibox'>
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class='ibox'>
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

This is what I'd like the end result to look like where the arrows are between the section boxes

[image: Id like to add these arrows between the boxes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, bootstrap doesn't seem to be doing you many favors here. Basically the font awesome icons should be in the `.col-md-3` divs and then you can add a class to make those `display:flex` and get rid of the default padding.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mlissne/pen/QxPggo)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <title></title>
    <style>
        .ibox {
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;

        }
    .add-flex {
      display: flex;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .add-flex:last-of-type .ibox {
      width: calc(100% - 36px);
    }
    i.glyphicon{
      margin-top: 100px;
      color: red;
      font-size: 36px
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class='container'>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 add-flex">
          <div class='ibox'>
          <h2>Safari bug warning!</h2>
          <p class="text-danger">As of v9.1.2, Safari exhibits a bug in which resizing your browser horizontally causes rendering errors in the justified nav that are cleared upon refreshing.</p>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          </div>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 add-flex">
            <div class='ibox'>

          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          </div>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
       </div>


        <div class="col-md-3 add-flex">
          <div class='ibox'>
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          </div>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-3 add-flex">
          <div class='ibox'>
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
         </div>

      </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a code pen with your code, without the i tag, i have added icons on the pseudo-element(:after), then hiding from the last item, you might have to remove them in the small screen view. Check if this helps you
[CodePen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MXRvmJ)

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <title></title>
    <style>
        .ibox {
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;

        }
.col-md-3:after {
      display: block;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f105";
  font-size: 20px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: -5px;
    top: 100px;
    color: red;
}
.col-md-3:last-child:after {
  display:none;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class='container'>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class='ibox'>
          <h2>Safari bug warning!</h2>
          <p class="text-danger">As of v9.1.2, Safari exhibits a bug in which resizing your browser horizontally causes rendering errors in the justified nav that are cleared upon refreshing.</p>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class='ibox'>

          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class='ibox'>
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class='ibox'>
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
         </div>

      </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

To hide the arrows in small screens, you can use media queries, see below

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-3:after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

This will hide the arrows in all the screens under 991 pixels.

Comment: how do you remove them if it is a small screen?

Comment: I have updated the code above to hide arrows in small screens, hope this helps